# Get keydown event without a textbox

Tags: c#, events, keydown

Im trying to do like that: If I press the key "P" a messagebox will open in the screen.But I need to do it without a textbox or other tool, I want to do that direct in the form.

I tried:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.P)
        { MessageBox.Show("Key P pressed"); }
    }
```

Comment: it is in my form1, i didnt the eventhandler..Its works if I do by pressing in a textbox, and if the event is on the textbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the KeyPress Event of the form. It just works fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, How can I do with Keypress?

Comment: let me add some snaps to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Winforms, on the form you're trying to catch the event on, make sure to set

```
Form1.KeyPreview = true;
```

[KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ensures that keyboard events anywhere on the particular form (such as to a textbox with focus) will still count as a keyboard event for the form itself.

Comment: Ohh, I wrote this.Keypreview = true, and now its working fine!! Thanks guys!

Comment: @user3491915 I don't understand what you mean, this is a solution for a windows for application

Comment: If this anser was helpful to you, be sure to vote it up or mark it as the answer